# JSON throws nil on every request

Tags: ios, json, swift

First time I'm trying to parse JSON data. The output comes out -
Course (success: zero, timestamp: nil, base: nil, date: nil, courses: nil)
Why is there nil everywhere?

I tried to change the value in the "Course" and "Currency" structures but did not lead to success

```
import UIKit
import JavaScriptCore


struct Course: Decodable {
    var success: Bool?
    var timestamp: Int?
    var base: String?
    var date: String?
    var rates: Currency?
}

struct Currency: Decodable {
    var USD: Float
    var AUD: Double
    var CAD: Double
    var PLN: Double
    var MXN: Double
    
}


class JsonViewContoller: UIViewController {
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        
        let urlData: String = "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=7ac2982c82da926b787fd2f089b110e5&symbols=USD,AUD,CAD,PLN,MXN&format=1"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlData) else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard error == nil else { return }
            do {
                let course = try JSONDecoder().decode(Course.self, from: data)
                print(Course())
                
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: `print(Course())` You are printing a new instance, not the one you decoded `course` (with a lower case).

Comment: Thank you so much! I broke my head while I was thinking what was the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code you don't need to use two structures to parse the above JSON data. You can easily get Data in a single Structure. I have modified your code as follows:-

```
import UIKit

struct Course: Codable {
    let success: Bool?
    let timestamp: Int?
    let base, date: String?
    let rates: [String: Double]?
}

class JsonViewContoller: UIViewController {
    
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        courseData()   
   } 

  fileprivate func courseData(){
        let urlData: String = "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=7ac2982c82da926b787fd2f089b110e5&symbols=USD,AUD,CAD,PLN,MXN&format=1"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlData) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            guard error == nil else { return }
            do {
                let course = try JSONDecoder().decode(Course.self, from: data)
                print(course)

            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }

        }.resume()

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm glad you help)

And how to get the value from struct "Course" and write it to another variable (to output to the ViewController?

Comment: false alarm (figured out)
let testing = course.rates? .USD

Comment: It's a dictionary, So you put your key and get your value like- let testing = course.rates?["USD"].